# Centered icon and text (React Material-UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am interested in best way to present a React Material-UI with icon and text, so it is all vertically aligned. Right now it does not work as expected, especially with conditional rendering.

```
               <Typography gutterBottom variant="subtitle2" component="h2" align="center">
                 <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center" wrap="nowrap">
                    {p.numRooms > 0 && (
                      <Grid item xs={2} alignItems="center">
                        <HotelRoundedIcon color="secondary" />
                        {p.numRooms}
                      </Grid>
                    )}
                    {p.area > 0 && (
                      <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <AspectRatioRounded color="secondary" />
                        {p.area}
                      </Grid>
                    )}
                  </Grid>
                </Typography>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add container in your secondary Grids to make icons and text vertically aligned.

```
 <Typography gutterBottom variant="subtitle2" component="h2" align="center">
                 <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center" wrap="nowrap">
                    {p.numRooms > 0 && (
                      <Grid item xs={2} container >
                        <HotelRoundedIcon color="secondary" />
                        {p.numRooms}
                      </Grid>
                    )}
                    {p.area > 0 && (
                      <Grid item xs={2} container>
                        <AspectRatioRounded color="secondary" />
                        {p.area}
                      </Grid>
                    )}
                  </Grid>
                </Typography>
```

Comment: You're great! What actually does adding this tag do? It does work though...

Comment: According to documentation: This basically converts your Grid component to flex or inline-flex. https://material-ui.com/components/grid/.  Then you can use 'justify' to change item horizontally and 'alignItems' to change them vertically.